# How do I make changes to a model in Django?

Tags: django, orm, django-models, versioning

How does Django handle changes to my Model? Or, what help does it offer me to do this?

I am thinking of a situation where I have already have published data to my DB which I don't want to lose, but I need to make changes to my data model - for example, adding extra fields to a particular class, changing the types of fields, etc. My understanding is that syncdb won't ever alter tables that already exist in the DB.

For example, let's say I have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hair_colour=CharField(max_length=50)
```

Things I might want to do to Person off the top of my head:

1. I wish to add an 'age' field.
2. I realise I want to use `IntegerField` instead of `CharField` for `phone_number` (whether this is a good idea or not, is out of scope...) - assuming it's possible.
3. I realise that I no longer wish to define `hair_colour` 'inline' within Person, because several people share the same hair colour - I wish instead to change this to be a foreign key to some other model.

Whilst I can imagine some of these are tough/impossible for the framework to 'guess' exactly what needs to be done to my data if all I do is update the models.py, I can imagine that there might still be some tooling to help enable it - does it exist?

In particular I imagine there must be some good patterns for option 1.

I'm very new to Django and have no experience with any other ORM-type stuff, which I think this is - I've always been a bit suspicious of ORMs, mainly for the reasons above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django itself will not attempt to modify an already created database table. What you are trying to do is typically called "Migration" and there are a couple of different Database Migration tools available for Django.

### [South](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/about.html)

- Schema Migrations
- Data Migrations
- Backwards Migrations

### [Nash Vegas](http://paltman.com/2009/02/24/nashvegas-a-simple-django-migration-tool/)

- Schema Migrations
- Data Migrations

### [Django Evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/)

- Schema Migrations
- *Data Migrations (Unknown)*
- *Backwards Migrations (Unknown)*

Of the three South is probably the most widely used but they each have different ways of dealing with migrations. You can see more details on the comparison on [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/database-migration/).

Comment: Thanks for this excellent & detailed reply. I think the key here was that I didn't realise this is called "migration", hence none of my existing searches on SO were fruitful. I've done a suggested edit to add links for the tools mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Much of what you're asking about can be done with the django project [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).  You add it as an INSTALLED_APP.  Create a baseline, then as your model changes it creates SQL statements to convert your tables and the rows with-in the tables to the new model format.